# regular expression to get output of single row in equally distributed multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have output formatted as single row in pipe separated format like 
`chq no, amount, bene name`
e.g :

```
123,100.00,test1 | 234,200.00,test2 | 345,300.00,test4 | ......... n
```

I am expecting output to be formatted based on count of records. If my query returns 50 pipe separated values (see below sql) then i want output to be equally distributed in 5 rows each of 10 records and so on.

```
123,100.00,test1 | 234,200.00,test2 | 345,300.00,test4 
111,100.00,test5 | 222,200.00,test6 | 333,300.00,test7
444,100.00,test3 | 555,200.00,test9 | 666,300.00,test8
```

I have one query tested, but output is not as expected

```
WITH w AS (
select count(*), ACCOUNTNO, rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (a,info || ' | ')).extract ('//text()'), ',')  info1
from (
select ACCOUNTNO, CHECKNO || ' , ' || AMOUNT || ' , ' || BENE_NAME info from test_alert_log
where trunc(TXNDATE) = '30-NOV-2015' and trim(ACCOUNTNO) = '1234567890'
)
group by ACCOUNTNO)

SELECT regexp_substr(info1,'[^|]+', 1, column_value)
  FROM w,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL 
                       FROM dual  
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(info1) + LENGTH(replace(info1, '|')) + 1
                   ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
         )
       )
WHERE regexp_substr(info1,'[^|]+', 1, column_value) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Update your post with output from your query showing exactly how the output is not as expected.

Comment: Upon further analysis, I see this prints your records in a single column, yes?  There is nothing in place to try to print multiple "records" on a single line so I suspect this is the problem.  What is the formula for calculating how many records will print on a line?  What if there is an odd number of records?  Just something to think about before coding a solution.  Oh and simplify the `CONNECT BY` line with this: `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(info1, '|') + 1`

Comment: Hi Gary, You are correct. As mentioned i am first formatting data in single row (123,100.00,test1 | 234,200.00,test2 | 345,300.00,test4 | ......... n) . Then i was trying to get expected output in rows for selected records (Lets say if i have 50 pipe separated records then i want that string to get  split into equal no of rows, as in this case there will be 5 rows containing 10 records each). So it is simply to break records into multiple rows. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick.  Start at line 14 where the connect by calculates how many rows of output you will need by first counting the delimiters and adding 1 to get the number of fields, then dividing by 2 (the desired number of "records" per line in my example) and running that through CEIL() (which basically rounds up) to handle partial rows if any.

Then look at line 7 where it outputs column_value-eth (really the row-eth) occurrence of the pattern of at least 1 but not more that 2 (must equal the 2 from the previous paragraph) patterns of 0 or more characters that are not a pipe followed by the delimiter or the end of the line.  It's greedy so it will grab 2 if they are available.  The trailing space/pipe/space is consumed (curse Oracle for no lookaheads in their regex) and must be removed from the output so I just use rtrim() for that.  The square brackets around the output are used just to illustrate no spaces are present and of course should be removed for production.

```
SQL> with w(info1) as (
  2    select '123,100.00,test1 | 234,200.00,test2 | 345,300.00,test3 | 111,100.00,test4 | ' ||
  3           '222,200.00,test5 | 333,300.00,test6 | 444,100.00,test7 | 555,200.00,test8 | ' ||
  4           '666,300.00,test9' from dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT column_value, '[' ||
  7         rtrim(regexp_substr(info1, '(([^|]*( \| |$)){1,2})', 1, column_value, NULL, 1), ' | ') ||
  8         ']' output
  9  FROM w,
 10       TABLE(
 11         CAST(
 12           MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL
 13                    FROM dual
 14                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ceil((REGEXP_COUNT(info1, ' \| ') + 1) / 2) -- Calculates rows
 15                   ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
 16             )
 17            );

COLUMN_VALUE OUTPUT
------------ ----------------------------------------
           1 [123,100.00,test1 | 234,200.00,test2]
           2 [345,300.00,test3 | 111,100.00,test4]
           3 [222,200.00,test5 | 333,300.00,test6]
           4 [444,100.00,test7 | 555,200.00,test8]
           5 [666,300.00,test9]

SQL>
```

So, the number "2" on lines 7 and 14 would just need to be changed to however many "records" you want to show on a line and it should be good to go for you.  Let us know how it works.